# wheel, pyzmq, bad file descriptor proplems in anaconda for deep learning

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pyzmq

I'm beginner of tensorflow.
I want to install, use jupyter notebook.
But that doesn't work in my notebook with bad file descripotr ploblem.
So I checked,deleted anaconda and tried to downgrade my pyzmq in 19.0.2 version.
but It has problem.
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyzmq
What should I do?
I downloaded visual studio.
I wrote my laptop's imformation
processor   11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-11370H @ 3.30GHz   3.30 GHz
RAM 16.0GB(15.8GB available)
system  64bit, x64 processor
Thank you for read.

How to solve Failed building wheel for pymzq19.0.2

Answer (score 0):

After installing Anaconda in your system, Please try again using the code below in jupyter to install the `pyzmq` package:

```
!conda install -c anaconda pyzmq #or

!conda install -c conda-forge pyzmq
```